# Heroku routing error when creating User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app that works perfectly in development and most of it works fine once deployed to Heroku. I'm getting an error when POSTing to `/users`, as processed by `UsersController#create`. I can't seem to track down what the actual problem is.

My Heroku Logs:

```
    2014-08-09T17:44:52.491925+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
    2014-08-09T17:44:52.543342+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 51ms (Views: 36.4ms |        ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.392552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users"   host=myflix-jirgens.herokuapp.com request_id=c4d84090-0c97-44b5-837a-2986895f4367   fwd="67.189.33.191" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=137ms status=500 bytes=1422
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.264626+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 67.189.33.191    at 2014-08-09 17:45:27 +0000
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.386331+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 119ms
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.276681+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.276686+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"JXXaLMfjX7jsKSQ3IBe5lqbtU0TatAN6fdnu8q9shtQ=", "user"=>  {"email"=>"me@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "full_name"=>"Me Myself"},    "invitation_token"=>"", "stripeToken"=>"tok_14PduC4NXe5wJuj7ZKn6mImQ",     "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"me@example.com"}
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.276687+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"JXXaLMfjX7jsKSQ3IBe5lqbtU0TatAN6fdnu8q9shtQ=", "user"=>   {"email"=>"me@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "full_name"=>"Me Myself"},    "invitation_token"=>"", "stripeToken"=>"tok_14PduC4NXe5wJuj7ZKn6mImQ",    "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"me@example.com"}
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.264616+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 67.189.33.191 at 2014-08-09 17:45:27 +0000
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.276684+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.545727+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myflix-jirgens.herokuapp.com request_id=cc5e62d6-6675-438a-ab57-1b4319ba1351 fwd="67.189.33.191" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=930
    2014-08-09T17:45:27.386990+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 119ms
```

My UsersController:

```
    class UsersController < InheritedResources::Base
      actions :new, :edit, :update
      before_filter :require_user, only: [:show]

      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        result = UserSignup.new(@user).sign_up(params[:stripeToken], params[:invitation_token])
        if result.successful?
          flash[:success] = "Thank you for registering! Please sign in."
          redirect_to sign_in_path
        else
          flash[:error] = result.error_message
          render :new
        end
      end  
    ...
    end
```

On Heroku, I am able to fill out the registration form and submit it. The error "We're sorry, but something went wrong" shows up on the page `/users`, so clearly the create function is not successful on Heroku while it is in my local environment.

Please forgive any newbie negligence. I'd appreciate any tips. Thank you.

UserSignup.rb:

```
    class UserSignup

      attr_reader :error_message

      def initialize(user)
        @user = user
      end

      def sign_up(stripe_token, invitation_token)
        if @user.valid?
          customer = StripeWrapper::Customer.create(
            :user => @user,
            :amount => 999, # amount in cents  currency is hardcoded in wrapper
            :card => stripe_token,
            :description => "Subscribtion charge for #{@user.email}"
          )
          if customer.successful?
            @user.customer_token = customer.customer_token
            @user.save
            handle_invitation(invitation_token)
            AppMailer.send_welcome_email(@user).deliver
            @status = :success
            self
          else
            @status = :failed
            @error_message = customer.error_message
            self
          end
        else
          @status = :failed
          @error_message = "Invalid user information. Please check your info."
          self
        end
      end

      def successful?
        @status == :success
      end

      private

      def handle_invitation(invitation_token)
        if invitation_token.present?
          invitation = Invitation.where(token: invitation_token).first
          @user.follow(invitation.inviter)
          invitation.inviter.follow(@user)
          invitation.update_column(:token, nil)
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: just a thought, have u ran ur migrations in production mode on heroku?

Comment: your code looks messed up. What is this line doing `result = UserSignup.new(@user).sign_up(params[:stripeToken], params[:invitation_token])`?

Comment: That line is referencing the UserSignup.rb service. I'll add that code above.

Comment: @RAJ Yep, I've run migrations over to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment -

As stated by `@Mandeep` in the comments, the problem will *likely* be with the `UserSignup.new` line; the question is *why*

I believe there are a number of areas to look at:

--

**Result**

Your line is as follows:

```
result = UserSignup.new(@user).sign_up(params[:stripeToken], params[:invitation_token])
```

The problem here is that you're trying to build another (seemingly unrelated) object with your original object. The core issue here is that this line just looks plain wrong (sorry for lack of scientific answer). I would focus on the *association* between your `User` and `UserSignup` objects, specifically using the `after_create` callback to populate the `UserSignup` functionality:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < InheritedResources::Base
   ...
   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:your, :user, :params).merge(stripe_token: params[:stripeToken], invitation_token: params[:invitation_token])
   end
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :stripe_token, :invitation_token

   before_create :create_user_signup
   after_create  :send_welcome_email

   private

   def create_user_signup
      result = UserSignup.new(self).sign_up(stripe_token, invitation_token)
      if result.successful?
         @user.customer_token = customer.customer_token
         # you might need a "return" here
      else
        errors.add("Stripe Error")
        # likewise, you might need "return false" here
      end
   end

   def send_welcome_email
      AppMailer.send_welcome_email(self).deliver
   end
end

#app/models/user_signup.rb
Class UserSignup
   def sign_up(stripe_token, invitation_token)
      return StripeWrapper::Customer.create(
        :user => @user,
        :amount => 999, # amount in cents  currency is hardcoded in wrapper
        :card => stripe_token,
        :description => "Subscription charge for #{@user.email}"
      )
   end
end
```

Although by no means a tried-and-tested piece of code, what I've attempted to do for you is modularize your calls. A big problem you have is that you're calling `User` model methods in `UserSignup`

In keeping with [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) principles, you want to make sure you have the respective methods with the respective object

--

**Stripe**

Secondly, you're submitting data to `Stripe`

The problem here could be rooted in several issues:

> - Your Stripe credentials might not be available on Heroku
> - Your `UserSignup` model might not be sending the right data to Stripe
> - Are you sure `Stripe` is working in your `production` environment?

One of the core issues people have with Heroku is not setting their [environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). Since STRIPE requires certain API keys to get going, you need to make sure you have set them in the backend

To do this, you can use Heroku's CLI (Heroku Toolbelt) as follows:

```
$ heroku config:set STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=your_secret_key
```